# How to run MVC 4 Code in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint-2013

I want to know **How to run MVC 4 Code in Sharepoint 2013?**

I had small application which, I want to plug into sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in Advance.

Manoj Kalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the front end web servers:

- Copy / publish your MVC 4 app to all of the WFE servers (create a separate folder for it i.e. c:\wwwroot\MyMVCApp)
- In IIS Manager create a new Application under your SharePoint web on each WFE (/MyMVCApp) and point it to the folder you previously published.
- Make sure to set the APP Pool correctly and the Anonymous Authentication identity if needed.